# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am getting this weird error... the primary key in my database is 'DocumentID' so I know that is not the issue. I am trying to get the select,edit & delete gridview buttons to work but I need the datakeynames to be set correctly for them to be available to use. any ideas?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsDocuments" EnableModelValidation="True"
        SelectedIndex="0" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="DocumentID, DocumentTitle, DocumentBody">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentID" HeaderText="DocumentID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentTitle" HeaderText="DocumentTitle" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentBody" HeaderText="DocumentBody" SortExpression="Body" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDocuments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blcDocumentationConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DocumentTitle], [DocumentBody] FROM [tblDocument]" />
```

Here is the stack trace...

```
    [HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a                 property with the name 'DocumentID'.] 
        System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) +8672869
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +2178
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +57
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +114
       System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +31
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +142
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +72
       System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171

   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you haven't selected the `documentid` column and hence it's not present in either datatable or dataview which you are binding to grid OR referencing that column through datatable.

Change your query to

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT [DocumentID],[DocumentTitle], [DocumentBody] FROM [tblDocument]" />
```

Answer (score 2):

1- First step you have to select the Documentid column in SELECT statement

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [DocumentID], [DocumentTitle], [DocumentBody] FROM [tblDocument]" />
```

2- You have to include it in datagridview COLUMN as you did:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsDocuments" EnableModelValidation="True"
        SelectedIndex="0" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="DocumentID, DocumentTitle, DocumentBody">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentID" HeaderText="DocumentID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentTitle" HeaderText="DocumentTitle" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentBody" HeaderText="DocumentBody" SortExpression="Body" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

3- If you are using Paging in datagridview AllowPaging="True" ,you have to SELECT also documentid on the event  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" to SELECT data in second and third page and so on:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="sdsDocuments" EnableModelValidation="True"
        SelectedIndex="0" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="DocumentID, DocumentTitle, DocumentBody">
```

Then on the event OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
                DataTable dt = // your SELECT statement //
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

if you dont use this void then you will get same error when you click page 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your sqldatasource does not return the DocumentId column.

Maybe you should change the datasource definition to this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDocuments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blcDocumentationConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [DocumentID], [DocumentTitle], [DocumentBody] FROM [tblDocument]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet Année = new DataSet();
Année.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Annees.xml"));

DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Number";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Number";
DropDownList1.DataSource = "Année";

DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Number'.

Comment: Are you posting this as an answer? Or reporting a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally occurs due to misspelled column names, hence one should recheck that.
2. If one specifies DataKeyNames property as "Sr. No." and the actual column name is "Sr. No" so It will throw the above error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).