# ASP.NET Error: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm getting this weird error now after I completed some steps listed in the website below with a previous problem.

`'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'`

This error is linked with the gridview after I put in `DataKeyNames="ID"`

Previous Problem:
[DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736052/databinding-system-data-datarowview-does-not-contain-a-property-with-the-name)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that a column called 'ID' is not present in the results set returned by the select query in the SqlDataSource assigned to the GridView.

You will either need to add the 'ID' column to your select query (if it exists)...

```
SELECT ID, <column name>, ..., <column name> FROM <table> etc
```

or alternatively assign the DataKeyNames as the name of the primary key column from your results set returned by the SqlDataSource assigned to the GridView.